# Galaxy: Dynamically update PageIndicator after creation

Tags: tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy

I'm developing an app for [Samsung Gear S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Gear_S3) and [Samsung Galaxy watches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Watch), using a [Tizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tizen) web application.

I'm trying to use a `PageIndicator` to show a user scrolling through a dynamic amount of pages generated after an API call, and these amount of pages change when users perform certain actions.
Documentation: https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/ui_fw_api/Mobile_UIComponents/mobile_PageIndicator.htm

Is it possible to update the amount of pages once an PageIndicator is created?

I tried destroying it and recreating it, but that didn't seem to work.

#### Code

```
function PageController() {
    /* Keep track of scope*/
    var _this = this;

    /* Tau elements */
    var pageIndicator = null;

    this.showIndicator = function(active, total) {
        if (pageIndicator != null) {
            pageIndicator.destroy();
        }

        var elPageIndicator = document.getElementById("pageIndicator");
        pageIndicator = tau.widget.PageIndicator(
          elPageIndicator, {maxPage: total, numberOfPages: total});

        console.log("Created");
        console.log(pageIndicator);
        pageIndicator.setActive(active);
    }
}
```

I also tried the configure() or _configure() functions I noticed exists in the object when using the console logger, without success.

#### Code

```
function PageController() {
    /* Keep track of scope*/
    var _this = this;

    /* Tau elements */
    var pageIndicator = null;

    this.showIndicator = function(active, total) {
        if (pageIndicator == null) {
            var elPageIndicator = document.getElementById("pageIndicator");
            pageIndicator = tau.widget.PageIndicator(
              elPageIndicator, {maxPage: total, numberOfPages: total});

            console.log("Created");
            console.log(pageIndicator);
        }

        console.log("Reconfigure");
        pageIndicator.configure({maxPage: total, numberOfPages: total});
        pageIndicator.refresh();
        pageIndicator.setActive(active);
        console.log(pageIndicator);
    }
}
```

Also trying to set the options manually via the pagindicatorobject.options.maxPage = my new amount and pageindicatorobject.options.amountPages = my new amount after which I try to perform a refresh() did not work.

#### Code

```
function PageController() {
    /* Keep track of scope*/
    var _this = this;

    /* Tau elements */
    var pageIndicator = null;

    this.showIndicator = function(active, total) {
        if (pageIndicator == null) {
            var elPageIndicator = document.getElementById("pageIndicator");
            pageIndicator = tau.widget.PageIndicator(
              elPageIndicator, {maxPage: total, numberOfPages: total});

            console.log("Created");
            console.log(pageIndicator);
        }

        console.log("Reconfigure");
        pageIndicator.options.maxPage = total;
        pageIndicator.options.numberOfPages = total;
        pageIndicator.refresh();
        pageIndicator.setActive(active);
        console.log(pageIndicator);
    }
}
```

In each case running the following Code

```
var pageController = new PageController();
pageController.showIndicator(x, y);
```

It would always give the same `pageIndicator` back in console, never replacing it when a new config was given. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the "Setting UI Component Options" section in *[UI Components](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/user-interface/tizen-advanced-ui/ui-components)* (Tizen).

To change options dynamically, you can use the widget `option` method.
In the example:

```
    console.log("Reconfigure");
    pageIndicator.option({maxPage: total, numberOfPages: total})
    pageIndicator.setActive(active);
    console.log(pageIndicator);
}
```

In this example there is no need to call the `refresh()` method.

Or you can use HTMLElement dataset to set options on the base widget HTMLElement and then call refresh on the widget.

Example:

```
    console.log("Reconfigure");
    elPageIndicator.dataset['maxPage'] = total;
    elPageIndicator.dataset['numberOfPages'] = total;
    pageIndicator.refresh();
    pageIndicator.setActive(active);
    console.log(pageIndicator);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, test the pageIndicator.option({maxPage: total, numberOfPages: total}) method and it works! So if I understand correctly, the refresh() function should only be called on tau objects if the HTML changed, not the JS.

Comment: PS: I also added this solution to the Samsung Developers forum, where I also asked this question. I have credited you. https://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=376890&startId=zzzzz~

Comment: Isn't a semicolon missing in the first example?